# Login into SQL Server 2014 using windows groups

Tags: sql-server

I have an domain admin user group and I have added it to SQL Server security. My account is added to the group. But I am not able to log in to SQL Server.

If I add my domain account individually to SQL Server, I can login using my Windows account. Can I login into SQL Server via a user group so I do not have to add the each individual account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  All that is required is to add the windows ad group to whatever role is appropriate to your configuration.

> SQL Server supports three types of logins:
>
> - A local Windows user account or trusted domain account. SQL Server
>     relies on Windows to authenticate the Windows user accounts.
> - Windows group. Granting access to a Windows group grants access to
>     all Windows user logins that are members of the group.
> - SQL Server login. SQL Server stores both the username and a hash of
>     the password in the master database, by using internal authentication
>     methods to verify login attempts.

Read more here [MSDN SQL Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669066(v=vs.110).aspx)

And this article has step by step with screen shots:  [Step By Step](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Authentication Mode, first you need to make sure that the user's identity is verified by Windows then SQL Server validates the account name and password using the Windows principal token in the operating system.

Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx